# forward_list: assign(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last) / assign(size_type __n, const _Tp& __val)

Tags: c++, c++11, forward-list

I have implemented a subset of the `forward_list` and wanted to test the method `assign(size_type __n, const _Tp& __val)` but I get a compiler error because the compiler wants to call the method `assign(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)` instead.

I have written the following snippet, just to illustrate the problem:

**test.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <utility> // Just to get the std::size_t

template<typename _Tp>
class forward_list {
  public:
    typedef std::size_t size_type;

    void assign(size_type n, const _Tp& val)
    {
      printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }

    template<typename _InputIterator>
    void assign(_InputIterator first, _InputIterator last)
    {
      printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
  forward_list<int> l;
  l.assign(10, 5);
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the execution is:

```
void forward_list<_Tp>::assign(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = int; _Tp = int]
```

I would like to have the method `assign(size_type __n, const _Tp& __val)` called.

Compiler version (just in case it matters): `g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2`

I have used similar signatures to the signatures used in the `std::forward_list` and, with the following code snippet (using the STL):

```
std::forward_list<int> l;
l.assign(10, 5);
```

The compiler knows that it has to call `assign(size_type __n, const _Tp& __val)` and doesn't get confused. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to SFINAE out the dual-iterator overload for things that are not actually iterators. (Also, since you are not writing the standard library, reserved names like `_Tp` and `_InputIterator` are off-limits.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `l.assign(10, 5);`, there are two viable overloads:

```
void assign(size_type n, const int& val)

template <>
void assign(int first, int last)
```

When we say that non-template functions are preferred to template functions, that is only true if the two have indistinguishable conversion sequences. But in this case, the function template will match exactly (both of your arguments are `int`, no conversion necessary), while the non-template will have to undergo promotation (have to promote `10` from `int` to `size_t`). So that's why the function template overload is preferred.

As to how to fix it, you just need to make the template *not* a viable overload. That involves writing a type_trait for input iterator, which using `void_t` is not hard:

```
template <typename... >
using void_t = void;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_input_iterator : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct is_input_iterator<T, void_t<
    decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<T>()),
    decltype(std::declval<T>() != std::declval<T>()),
    decltype(*std::declval<T>()),
    decltype(++std::declval<T>()),
    decltype(std::declval<T>()++)
    >> : std::true_type { };
```

And then require `is_input_iterator`:

```
template <typename _InputIterator,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<is_input_iterator<_InputIterator>::value>>
void assign(_InputIterator first, _InputIterator last);
```

There are lots of other ways to do this sort of thing, I just happen to like `void_t`. Regardless of which way you do it, you have to ensure that the template simply isn't viable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't found anything similar in my file `bits/forward_list.h`, so that's why I wondered why it works in the STL (probably something similar is included somehow).

Comment: @3.1415 Mine looks like `template <typename _InputIterator, typename = std::_RequireInputIter<_InputIterator>> void assign(_InputIterator, _InputIterator);`

Comment: Mine looks like (g++ 4.7.2) `template<typename _InputIterator> void assign(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)`. I have just checked a newer version and it looks like as yours. So now I can see the missing parts in my implementation :-). Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The `assign` overload that you want to be called takes an `unsigned` integral type as the first argument, but you're passing it two signed integers. If you change the call to

```
l.assign(10U, 5);  // make the first argument unsigned
```

the first `assign` overload is called. But clearly, this is not the right solution to your problem in general.

You need to constrain the `assign` template so that it is only viable when the type of the arguments satisfy requirements for iterators. One way to do this is to inspect [`iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) for the type involved. If the [`iterator_category`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) satisfies the requirements of an *InputIterator*, then the function template can be used.

```
template<typename InputIterator>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_base_of<std::input_iterator_tag,
                    typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::iterator_category
                   >::value
         >::type
    assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
  printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3aafefb16cd026d)

Note that technically the above solution isn't guaranteed to work before C++17 (or whatever it'll be called) because `iterator_traits` isn't required to be SFINAE friendly until then, and it could result in a hard error instead of substitution failure. But chances are your implementation's `iterator_traits` is already SFINAE friendly, and you won't run into any issues.

---

[`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) isn't guaranteed to be included by `<utility>`, use one of the headers listed on the linked page.

Don't use identifiers that begin with an underscore and are followed by an uppercase characters, those are [reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/241631) for the implementation.

Comment: Thank you. But, why does it work in the STL (or, how is something similar included in the file `bits/forward_list.h`)?.

Comment: @3.1415 I see `template<typename _InputIterator, typename = std::_RequireInputIter<_InputIterator>> void assign(...)`; and `_RequireInputIter` is an alias template defined in *stl_iterator_base_types.h*, it's very similar to what my `enable_if` expression is doing, except it uses `is_convertible` instead of `is_base_of`

Comment: That was the missing part in my forward_list.h, mine looks like (g++ 4.7.2) `template<typename _InputIterator> void assign(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)`. I cannot upvote your answer because I have no enough points and can only accept one answer instead of two.

Comment: @3.1415 Welcome to StackOverflow! You'll do well here if you continue posting questions that have complete, compilable examples as you did above :) Don't worry about the upvote, come back when you have enough rep and upvote both our answers :)